# Show NSData as binary in a NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, binary, nsdata

I have a binary file (file.bin) in the resources folder, I want to read it and show it as binary. The idea its to put the binary information into a array, but, at first, I'm trying to show it in a UILabel, like that:

`   NSData *databuffer;
    NSString *stringdata;

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"bin"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

if (myData) {  
        stringdata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myData description]]; 
        labelfile.text = stringdata;
}
```

`

But it shows the data in HEX. How can I do it in binary to put it in a NSMutableArray? 
Thanks.

Comment: By "in binary" do you literally mean "base 2 notation"?

Comment: Yes, like: NSSTRING string = @"01000101000.."

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need to write your own binary decoder.  I wrote a language once that would interpret B"101010.." as a binary literal, but I've never seen any standard language that would read or format binary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if there is anything native that does that but I can propose a workaround solution. Why don't you do your own function that does the conversion. Here is my example:

In the place you get the Hex values:

```
NSString *str = @"Af01";
NSMutableString *binStr = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(NSUInteger i=0; i<[str length]; i++)
{
    [binStr appendString:[self hexToBinary:[str characterAtIndex:i]]];
}
NSLog(@"Bin: %@", binStr);
```

The workaround function:

```
- (NSString *) hexToBinary:(unichar)myChar
{
    switch(myChar)
    {
        case '0': return @"0000";
        case '1': return @"0001";
        case '2': return @"0010";
        case '3': return @"0011";
        case '4': return @"0100";
        case '5': return @"0101";
        case '6': return @"0110";
        case '7': return @"0111";
        case '8': return @"1000";
        case '9': return @"1001";
        case 'a':
        case 'A': return @"1010";
        case 'b':
        case 'B': return @"1011";
        case 'c':
        case 'C': return @"1100";
        case 'd':
        case 'D': return @"1101";
        case 'e':
        case 'E': return @"1110";
        case 'f':
        case 'F': return @"1111";
    }
    return @"-1"; //means something went wrong, shouldn't reach here!
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot!!. It looks weird because my file is in binary and I have to convert it but its ok.

Comment: Happy for you :) Please remember to accept this answer if it solved your problem so it appears as a correct answer.

Comment: What about G through to Z?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff read the question again, the data is in HEX and not English letters, therefore there is no G to Z in HEX. This answer converts Hexadecimal values to Binary. If you want English letters then you have to use the ASCII table to get the integer value of each character and then convert that integer to binary.