# How to send Octect-stream data through PUT in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I have a file which i have to upload to a server.The requirements of server are : PUT , Content-Type : application/octet-stream.

I created the NSData with following code :

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

AFAIK this will be in hex format and data to be send in binary form. How to do the conversion ? There must be a straight way which i am not aware of !!

Answer (score 2):

See the official documentation :

> NSData and its mutable subclass NSMutableData provide data objects,
>   object-oriented wrappers for byte buffers. Data objects let simple
>   allocated buffers (that is, data with no embedded pointers) take on
>   the behavior of Foundation objects.

The NSData is not by default in hex as you assume but is in the form of a byte array.

If you want to show the data as a string containing the binary content, take a look at the function in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664958/show-nsdata-as-binary-in-a-nsstring) .