# How to convert PDF to binary in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a PDF file, got it from iCloud and want to convert that PDF file to binary.

**Code Snippet :**

```
-(IBAction)iCloudDriveFullFolder:(id)sender
{
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                                                                                                            inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
    documentPicker.delegate = self;

    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - iCloud files
- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    if (controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerModeImport)
    {
         NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully imported %@", [url lastPathComponent]];

        NSLog(@"alertMessage %@",alertMessage);
}
```

Using this code i got the PDF file from iCloud. **alertMessage** got it that PDF file. how can i convert into binary. help me. thanks advance.

Comment: You can use following code
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strURL];

Comment: how i use this code. pass the alertMessage string to  strURL . but i got null.

Comment: Here you need to provide the path url of PDF. After you imported the PDF, you must have kept it some where, use that path. I have never import something like this, but if you have the path, then you can use the method to get binary data

Comment: NSString *alertMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully imported %@", [url lastPathComponent]]; "alertMessage" got pdf file. how can i convert it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a `NSData` object for `NSURL`:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url]
```

(I have no way to test for you, if it doesn't work you have the get the path: `url.path`)

and then you can get the binary from `NSData` with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10665456/5109911) answer

Comment: saw that link how can i assign the nsdata to string help me.. help me.